# ¿Como funciona un bucle for en una lista?

Tags: python-3.x, bucle-for

No entiendo muy bien como funciona este bucle **' for '** en esta lista:

```
lista_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lista_2 = [i for i in lista_1]
print(lista_1)
```

Si entiendo el bucle, lo que no entiendo es porque antes del bucle **' for '** esta la **' i '** si la quito da error, así que mi pregunta es ¿Porque se sitúa la **' i '** en ese lugar?

**Desde ya gracias por sus respuestas!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que estás viendo es una sintaxis llamada *expresión generadora*. Este tipo de expresiones generan una serie de valores, para lo cual internamente usan un bucle `for`, pero los valores que generan se pueden computar con una expresión arbitraria.

La sintaxis general de la expresión generadora es:

```
expresion for elemento in iterable
```

El `for` causa una iteración sobre el `iterable` que pongas al final (que puede ser una lista, o cualquier otra cosa sobre la que se pueda iterar). En cada iteración, la variable `elemento` toma un valor de ese iterable. Entonces se evalúa la `expresion` que aparece al principio. Habitualmente esa `expresion` contiene de alguna forma al `elemento`, como por ejemplo aqui:

```
(i+1)*2 for i in range(5)
```

En este caso el iterable es `range(5)`, que va devolviendo en cada iteración los números `0, 1, 2, 3` y `4`, que son los valores que va tomando la `i`. Pero la expresión pone `(i+1)*2`, de modo que esa expresión tomará los valores `2, 4, 6, 8,` y `10`. La expresión generadora por tanto irá creando estos últimos.

Cuando encierras entre corchetes una expresión generadora, tienes lo que se llama una *list comprehension*, que simplemente consiste en que se crea una lista con los datos generados por la expresión generadora. En el ejemplo anterior se crearía la lista `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

Así pues queda explicado tu caso:

```
lista_2 = [i for i in lista_1]
```

La expresión en este caso es `i`, es decir, cada elemento se deja tal como estaba, sin transformar. Así que al final `lista_2` tendrá los mismos elementos que `lista_1`. En este caso la asignación es equivalente a `lista_2 = list(lista_1)`. Observa que no es lo mismo que `lista_2 = lista_1` ya que en este segundo caso estaríamos haciendo que ambas listas se refiriesen al mismo objeto en memoria, mientras que en el primero estamos creando una lista nueva, eso sí, con los mismos elementos que la primera.

### Detalles adicionales

- La expresión no tiene por qué contener `i`. Por ejemplo lo siguiente sería válido:

  ```
  [ "hola" for i in lista_1 ]
  ```

  En este caso la expresión es `"hola"`, por lo que se crearía una nueva lista con la palabra `"hola"` repetida tantas veces como elementos tuviera `lista_1`.
- Las expresiones generadoras admiten también otra forma, con una condición al final, así:

  ```
  expresion for elemento in iterable if condicion
  ```

  En este caso, si la condición es cierta se evalúa la expresión y se añade al resultado, pero si la condición es falsa, no se hace.

  Por ejemplo, la siguiente asignación copiaría a `lista_2` únicamente las letras mayúsculas que hubiera en `lista_1`:

  ```
  lista_2 = [i for i in lista_1 if i.isupper() ]
  ```
- Las expresiones generadoras pueden ser aún más complicadas, pues admiten `for` anidados.
- Si la expresión generadora va entre paréntesis en vez de entre corchetes, entonces no se crea ninguna lista, sino que la expresión entera es otro iterador sobre el que se puede iterar, o se puede pasar como parámetro a funciones que esperen un iterador.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!! Estuvo excelente!

Answer (score 1):

Con la instrucción

```
for i in lista_1
```

recorres la lista `lista_1`, introduciendo en `i` cada uno de sus elementos en cada iteración.

Al colocar la `i` otra vez delante del `for`, añades a una nueva lista `lista_2` cada uno de los valores que va tomando `i`

Tal vez con una lista y una tupla lo veas mejor:

```
lista_1 = ('a', 'b', 'c')
lista_2 = [i for i in lista_1]
print(lista_2)
```